# merge sort with large number of integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Need to sort a large number of integers which cannot hold into memory. Wondering if Merge sort is the right way? My solution like this,

1. Using memory based sorting for each 5% of integers, which could hold into memory, using quick sort which performs efficiently in memory;
2. After each 20 chunks are sorted, using merge sort to sort the 20 lists, for merge sort, I just need to load part of each file into memory, and load next part of the same list if current part of the same list is fully sorted into final results. Since each of the 20 lists are sorted, and I just need to load part of the chunks from head to tail sequentially, so memory is affordable.

I am not sure if it is the right way for large number of integer sorting?

Comment: probably something to look into is external sorting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: @Moogs, thanks for the info and I think merge sort is external sort?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way. I've used it many times. Except I do a 2-way merge multiple times, not a 20-way merge.

Comment: Yes, what you have described is exactly the external merge sort algorithm.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I think 20-way may be faster? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if 20-way will be faster or not. You make fewer passes over the data, but the comparison process is much more complex. Given the answer you've received, I'll guess somebody has already studied this and decided 16-way is optimum, but I can't confirm that.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice Mark. Have a good night. :)

Comment: Although the memory requirement doubles, a counting / radix sort would be much faster for the memory part of the sort. How many bits per integer is this data?

Comment: What kind of integers are they? Regular 32 bit ints?

Comment: @displayName, good question, they are integers, and most of them are 1-100, any good advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since,

> they are integers, and most of them are 1-100

all you need is [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

---

It is very simple in implementation.

1. Create an array of 100 ints (or `HashMap<int, int>`) called `intCounts` (take 64-bit ints if you think 32-bit can overflow)
2. One by one read the integers that you have to sort
3. For every `inputInteger` to be sorted, just do `intCounts[inputInteger]++`
4. After you have read all integers, `intCounts[i]` tells how many times you saw integer `i` in your large set of integers
5. Just iterate over your `intCounts` from least index to highest index
6. Write back `i` a total of `intCounts[i]` times
7. You have written back a sorted list of all your input integers now.

Comment: displayName, smart and smart. :)

Comment: @LinMa: Nothing smart about it. I'm only informed. And now, so are you.

Comment: Hope you can always help to inform me. Love to learn from you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The GNU sort program (like its Unix predecessor) uses an in-memory sort followed by as many 16-way merges as needed. See the code here to read more:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c#n306

Comment: Thanks cliffordheath, for 16-way merges, do they using external storage based merge sort?

Comment: A 16-way or any k-way sort is usually a merge sort, in this case an external merge sort. [wiki article - external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) .

Comment: @rcgldr, how to decide optimize k for k-way? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa - depends if the number of merge passes is decreased by going to a larger k. Once you have code that can handle a k-way merge, a larger k doesn't make it more complicated, but a even a basic k-way merge is complicated since when the end of a run is reached, it's a k-1 way merge, then a k-2 way merge, and then just the remainder of one run left, which is copied. For k > 2 to be effective, large I/O's are needed to reduce random access overhead (assuming you don't have 2 x k devices or are using SSD drives to sort with).

Comment: @rcgldr, what do you mean "number of merge passes"? Thanks.

Comment: @Lin: I pointed to the code so you could read it! Yes, they use temporary files. Each N-way merge sort produces 1 file - so if you have M files to start with, the required number of merges goes with order of log-to-base-N(M). So the larger N is, the fewer the number of merges

Comment: @LinMa - To follow up on cliffordheath's comment, the initial pass of the example code creates M temporary sorted files, where M = (file size) / (effective buffer size). Using a single file and M file pointers would be an alternative, but my guess is at the time the example was written, file pointers were 32 bits. Both Linux and Windows now have 64 bit alternatives for fseek() and ftell().